# How to align button to the right in text container?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have container and in it I have three child elements: h2, p and button. I want make a button on the right of h2 and p aligned center. The html can't be changed, only css using flexbox or grid.

```css
div {
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  padding: 20px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

div h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div p {
  margin: 0
}

div button {
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <p>Description test description</p>
  <button>submit</button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear you want h2 in left, p in center and button on right side. Correct?

Comment: In this case, I would use absolute positioning. Css grid seems overdone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Grid to change the `button` position:

```css
div {
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  padding: 20px 40px;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

div h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div p {
  margin: 0
}

div button {
  padding: 15px 20px;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <p>Description test description</p>
  <button>submit</button>
</div>
```